# Need help resolving the issue ''AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary' ''

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Need help resolving the issue `'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'`.

```
def model(inputs):

    batch_size,height,width=config.BATCH_SIZE,config.IMAGE_SHAPE[0],config.IMAGE_SHAPE[1]
    
    with slim.arg_scope(resnet_v2.resnet_arg_scope()):
          #net, end_points = resnet_v2.resnet_v2_101(inputs, 1001, is_training=False)
          net, end_points = resnet_v2.resnet_v2_152(inputs,
                                                    2048,
                                                    is_training=True,
                                                    global_pool=False,
                                                    reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                                                    output_stride=config.OUTPUT_STRIDE)
    #print(net)
    kp_maps = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(net,num_outputs = config.NUM_KP,
                                             kernel_size=(1,1),activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,stride=1,scope='kp_maps',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

    short_offsets = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(net,num_outputs = 2*config.NUM_KP,
                                             kernel_size=(1,1),activation_fn=None,stride=1,scope='short_offsets',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
                          
    mid_offsets = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(net,num_outputs = 4*config.NUM_EDGES,
                                             kernel_size=(1,1),activation_fn=None,stride=1,scope='mid_offsets',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    
    long_offsets = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(net,num_outputs = 2*config.NUM_KP,
                                             kernel_size=(1,1),activation_fn=None,stride=1,scope='long_offsets',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    
    seg_mask = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(net,num_outputs = 1,
                                             kernel_size=(1,1),activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,stride=1,scope='seg_mask',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)


    model.summary()
```

I am trying to print the summary of the model

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: Is `model` both the name of a function and the name of a variable?  You have `model.summary`, but I have no idea where `model` is defined.

Comment: You do not seem to be using Keras, you cannot really use model.summary() as you have not built a Keras model in this code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in the `model.summary()` model is the reference to the current function.

You're trying to use the recursive function reference.

try to pass the model reference to this function along with inputs & use that to get the summary.

```
def model(model_obj, inputs):

    ...
    model_obj.summary()
```